# How to prove This Equation between Riemann Tensor and Killing Vector?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, vector-fields

How to prove This Equation between Riemann Tensor and Killing Vector?

$$
[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\rho]\xi_\sigma = R_{\sigma\nu\mu\rho}\xi^\nu
$$

I know

$$
R(\vec{X},\vec{Y},\vec{Z})=[\nabla_{\vec{X}}, \nabla_{\vec{Y}}]\vec{Z} - \nabla_{[\vec{X}, \vec{Y}]}\vec{Z}
$$

but why the second part equals zero?

Comment: Does this help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512281/

Comment: I use the same method as physics.stackexchange.com/a/512311/356911 and my question is just how the 5th equation there goes to the 6th equation which uses $[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\rho]\xi_\sigma=R_{\sigma\nu\mu\rho}\xi^\nu$

Answer (score 0):

The fifth equation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/512311/edit) is
$$\nabla_\mu\nabla_\sigma \mathcal{K}_\rho-\nabla_\mu\nabla_\rho \mathcal{K}_\sigma+[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\rho]\mathcal{K}_\sigma-[\nabla_\rho,\nabla_\sigma]\mathcal{K}_\mu+[\nabla_\sigma,\nabla_\mu]\mathcal{K}_\rho=0$$

Here is an outline of how I would reach to the next step shown there. From Killing's equation, we can write
$$ \nabla_\mu\nabla_\sigma \mathcal{K}_\rho = - \nabla_\mu\nabla_\rho \mathcal{K}_\sigma  $$
This reduces the first two terms to
$$  \nabla_\mu\nabla_\sigma \mathcal{K}_\rho - \nabla_\mu\nabla_\rho \mathcal{K}_\sigma  = 2 \nabla_\mu\nabla_\sigma\mathcal{K}_\rho$$

For the rest, you can use the equation defining the Reimann tensor, i.e.,
$$[\nabla_\mu ,\nabla_\sigma ]\mathcal{K}^\rho=R^\rho_{\mu\sigma\nu}\mathcal{K}^\nu$$

To lower the index on $R^\rho_{\sigma\mu\nu}$ you can use the metric, i.e.,
$$ R_{\sigma\delta\mu\nu} = g_{\sigma \rho}R^\rho_{\delta\mu\nu}$$

This gives

$$[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\sigma]\mathcal{K}_\nu=g_{\nu \rho}R^\rho_{\mu\sigma\delta}\mathcal{K}^\delta = R_{\mu\sigma \delta\nu}\mathcal{K}^\delta$$

the rest goes as shown in the link.

Comment: @Ghoster ah thanks for that.

Comment: So $[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\sigma]\xi^\rho = R^\rho_{\mu\sigma\nu}\xi^\nu$ is the definition of the Riemann tensor? I just want to know how this is proved. I know $R(\vec{X},\vec{Y},\vec{Z})=[\nabla_{\vec{X}}, \nabla_{\vec{Y}}]\vec{Z} - \nabla_{[\vec{X}, \vec{Y}]}\vec{Z}$

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu Yours is similar to mine. The last term that has [X,Y] has been set to zero  as the vector fields in the chosen coordinate induced basis commute.